# Reclaim space on volume for bootable partition

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk, growpart

I have a volume on Centos 8 that has 10G to spare:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1     259:0    0  80G  0 disk 
└─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0  80G  0 part /db
nvme0n1     259:2    0  30G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:3    0   1M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:4    0  20G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:5    0   1G  0 part [SWAP]
```

I read some documentation that told me to reclaim it like this:

```
$ sudo growpart -v /dev/nvme0n1 2
update-partition set to true
resizing 2 on /dev/nvme0n1 using resize_sfdisk_dos
62914560 sectors of 512. total size=32212254720 bytes
## sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/nvme0n1
label: dos
label-id: 0xa323d5eb
device: /dev/nvme0n1
unit: sectors

/dev/nvme0n1p1 : start=        2048, size=        2048, type=83
/dev/nvme0n1p2 : start=        4096, size=    41938911, type=83, bootable
/dev/nvme0n1p3 : start=    41943040, size=     2097152, type=82
max_end=41943040 tot=62914560 pt_end=41943007 pt_start=4096 pt_size=41938911
NOCHANGE: partition 2 could only be grown by 33 [fudge=2048]
$
```

How can I assign the empty disk to the bootable partition?

Answer (score 1):

the free space is in the after of nvme0n1p3, not between nvme0n1p2 and nvme0n1p3.

To spare nvme0n1p2, you need to

First swapoff and remove nvme0n1p3 (swap).

Then extent nvme0n1p2 (/).

Then recreate nvme0n1p3 (swap)